# What is the relationship between Calculus and Vector Calculus?

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields

Im a highschool student, and i read a book about calculus.
And Im curious about vector calculus.

Vector Calculus = vector + calculus  ??
is it right? if so, is calculus a higher concept of vector calculus?

Answer (score -1):

Not really.

Etymologically, *calculus* refers to pebbles of chalk (latin *calculi*) that were used in counting and simple computations (like with an abacus). Today, *calculus* could best be taken to mean "way of computation". This way, we have

- vector calculus
- differential calculus
- propositional calculus

and more. But when we use "calculus" alone, we tend to use it as a short for  "infinitesimal calculus".